# Многопоточность - в чём смысл std::thread.join()?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Сколько использую потоки, никогда их не `join()`-ил... В моём понимании, для реализации многопоточности `thread`-ы нужно "отпускать в вольное плавание" при помощи `detach()`, и регулировать мьютексами доступ к общим участкам памяти.

Объясните пожалуйста где я заблуждаюсь?... Ведь везде рекомендуют использовать `join()`, но я не понимаю какой смысл вызвать в функции поток с `join()` и остановить тем самым её выполнение пока поток не отработает... Где же тогда многопоточность?

[UPDATE]

Прочитав ответы, я так и не понял где многопоточность, например, в этом коде?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex m_console;
void Log(){
    for( int i = 0; i < 127; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_console);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
void Lag(){
    for( char i = 0; i < 127; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_console);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::thread(Log).join();
    std::thread(Lag).join();
    for( int i = 0; i < 127; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_console);
        std::cout << "azaza" << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если всё выполнится поочерёдно, где тогда распараллеливание, ради которого потоки и существуют? Даже если локи убрать, информация в консоли не перемешается, как ожидается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от того, что именно вам нужно. Например, вы распараллелили какие-то вычисления - и что теперь вам делать? Например, ваши потоки каждый считает какое-то значение, которые потом нужно просуммировать. Как вы это сделаете, отправив их в `detach`? будете постоянно опрашивать какие-то флаги, которые эти потоки должны выставить? :)

Ваши потоки нужно было вызывать примерно так:

```
std::thread Lo(Log);
std::thread La(Lag);
for( int i = 0; i < 127; i++){
    std::cout << "azaza" << std::endl;
}
Lo.join();
La.join();
```

Только учтите, что мьютексы там не нужны, `cout` и так достаточно умный, и что вы при этих 127 числах просто ничего не увидите - первый поток просвистит, пока второй будет создаваться... Или сделайте их побольше, или добавьте, например, задержку небольшую...

Comment: И зачем тогда новые потоки? Можно ж в одном все вычисления делать-_-

Comment: @АртурКлочко Это прикалываетесь? :)  Как зачем? Каждый считает свою часть. Работа делится между потоками и выполняется параллельно. Но вместо опросов флагов - вам все равно нужно дождаться последнего из потоков - вызываем `join` и не мучимся...

Comment: Так, стоп. Создание объекта класса `thread` это уже и выполнение потока? Или поток выполняется методом `join` \ `detach`?

Comment: Это уже и выполнение. `join` - ожидание завершения, `detach` - поток живет своей жизнью, мы от него отказались :)

Comment: @Harry, понял, про распараллеливание, но где же оно в примере, который я добавил в вопросе? Может я не так вызываю потоки?

Comment: Конечно, не так. См. дополнение в ответе.

Comment: @Harry, погонял код, механику понял... Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread::join` нужен в двух случаях:

1. Ваша программа завершается, вы вот-тот выйдите из `main()`, и надо корректно завершить работу потоков (уничтожить объекты, закрыть дескрипторы, опустошить кеши и т. д.). Тогда вы сначала как-то уведомляете их о необходимости завершения, а затем вызываете для каждого из них `join()`. Без этого ожидания стандартная библиотека прибьёт процесс сразу же по выходу из `main()`.
2. Вы единоразово распараллелили вычисления и теперь вам надо дождаться результатов, чтобы собрать их в кучу и продолжить выполнение.

Comment: если поток не фоновый, то процесс не завершится. Будет висеть процесс, в котором работает повисший поток.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, [а вот и нет](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function): *Выполнение `return` ... эквивалентно нормальному выходу из функции (которое уничтожает объекты с автоматическим временем жизни) с последующим вызовом `std::exit` ... (`std::exit` уничтожает статические объекты и завершает программу).* То есть все потоки «прибиваются» и процесс завершается.

Answer (score 1):

`thread.join` приостанавливает выполнение текущего потока до тех пор, пока поток, для которого было вызвано `join()` не завершится.

Обычно потоки применяются для выполнение неблокирующей ресурсо-, время-затратной операции.Оказывается, что намного удобнее не отпускать потоки в свободное плавание, а контролировать их из одного главного потока, приостанавливая его, когда он ожидает значения из дочерних потоков (этот подход рекомендуют большинство источников).

Более того, если мы отпустим поток в свободное плавание через `thread.detach()` мы не сможем его контролировать и получим кучу сообщений об ошибках и утечку памяти если таких потоков будет много. Поток, для которого был вызван `detach` не можем быть использован в контексте функции `join()`. Специфика потоков такова, что они знают, какой поток является родительским для них и только родительский поток в Си и плюсах может вызвать `join()` и только для своих дочерних потоков.

В заключение: существует поверье, что чем меньше мютексов, тем лучше, они сильно захламляют код и делают его трудно понимаемым. Поэтому не сильно ими увлекайтесь.

Comment: В отличии от процессов (создаваемых вызовом `fork()`), среди потоков нет иерархии родитель-сын (по крайней мере в Linux реализации `pthread_`). Поэтому join может вызывать *любой* из потоков. Важно лишь, чтобы поток, `pthread_t` которого передается в join не был detached

Answer (score 1):

В примере вашего кода все выполняется с точностью до наоборот. Вы запускаете новый поток `td::thread(Log)`, который, как и ожидалось, будет выполнять функцию Log. Но при этом вы сразу вызываете `join()`  который приостанавливает текущий поток до тех пор, пока поток, для которого он вызван не окончит свое выполнение. Вы делаете это два раза. И два раза вы останавливаете главный поток программы. В результате будут созданы два потока, **но** второй создаться и выполнится только после того, как окончится первый, поскольку для него вызван `join()`

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex m_console;
void Log(){
    for( int i = 0; i < 127; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_console);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
void Lag(){
    for( char i = 0; i < 127; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_console);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // don't call join
    std::thread one(Log);
    std::thread two(Lag);
    for( int i = 0; i < 127; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_console);
        std::cout << "azaza" << std::endl;
    }
    // but call there
    one.join();
    two.join();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system("pause");` ыыы. Sorry, это уже почти мем тут.

Answer (score 0):

Книга "Практика многопоточного программирования" сообщает по поводу вызова join и остановки основного потока:

"*... запускать функцию в отдельном потоке нет смысла, поскольку первый поток во время ожидания не будет выполнять никакой полезной работы. Но в реальном коде исходный поток будет либо выполнять полезную работу, либо запускать несколько потоков для выполнения полезной работы, прежде чем входить в режим ожидания их завершения.*"

Т.е. одно дело, начать выполнять дополнительный поток, остановив основной, по сути, перенеся одну функциональности с одного потока в другой - это бессмысленно, а вот если до вызова join наделать делов и/или запустить кучу потоков и ждать их завершения, то это уже другое.

```
 std::thread t1(f1);
 t1.join();
 std::thread t2(f2);
 t2.join();
 // смысла нет

 std::thread t1(f1);
 std::thread t2(f2);
 // .....
 t1.join();
 t2.join();
 // смысл есть
```

P.S. может я недопонял вопрос...